# How to divide two rows making a third row of the result?

Tags: r

So what I currently have is a dataframe that looks like the following...

```
rowId   x1    x2    x3    x4
  1     50    40    30    20
  2      5     5     5     5
```

and what I want is to divide row 1 by row 2 creating a third row with the result, like this...

```
rowId   x1    x2    x3    x4
  1     50    40    30    20
  2      5     5     5     5
  3     10     8     6     4
```

what's a simple way of going about doing this?

Comment: For me I usually Transpose the data.frame.

Comment: Or you can just divide the rows and then change the ID

Comment: `mydata[3,]=c(3,mydata[1,-1]/mydata[2,-1])`

Answer (score 2):

You could do like this:

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
x1    x2    x3    x4
50    40    30    20
 5     5     5     5")

df <- rbind ( df, df[1, ] / df[2, ] )
```

Comment: Are you sure you get the right answer ? `rowId` became one of the column?

Comment: just need `df[1, ]` to `df[1, -1]`

Comment: @Wen I see what you mean. But I shouldn't have included the row id in the first place. That is why I changed my code.