# Divide 2 rows to create new row

Tags: r

Extremely easy question that has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44928346/how-to-divide-two-rows-making-a-third-row-of-the-result) but I don't understand the error that I'm getting.

All I want to do is divide two rows in a table (*not* dataframe) and create a new row at the bottom:

```
           a     b       c       d           e   Total
 A         460      1063    1680    2535     76  5814
 B         554      4974    3052    7094     239 15913
 Total     1014     6037    4732    962      315 21727

    table[4,] <- table[1,] / table[3,] 

Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, 4, , value = ...  : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

Comment: You can share output of `dput` on your table?

Comment: In `rbind ( df, df[1, ] / df[2, ] )` (answer in your link) substitute `table` for `df`. The error comes from trying to assign the non-existent 4th row a value.

Answer (score 0):

Using the iris dataset by example to add rows 1 and 2:

```
attach(iris)
tab<-table(iris$Species,iris$Petal.Width)
new_row <- tab[1,] + tab[2,]
tab<-rbind(tab,new_row)
```

Results:

```
> tab
           0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 1 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8 1.9 2 2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4 2.5
setosa       5  29   7   7   1   1 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 0   0   0   0   0   0
versicolor   0   0   0   0   0   0 7   3   5  13   7  10   3   1   1   0 0   0   0   0   0   0
virginica    0   0   0   0   0   0 0   0   0   0   1   2   1   1  11   5 6   6   3   8   3   3
new_row      5  29   7   7   1   1 7   3   5  13   7  10   3   1   1   0 0   0   0   0   0   0
```